# How can I prevent the page from scrolling down when using jQuery UI hide("slide")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

here is my code :

```
$('#pagelinks > a').click(function () { 
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
setTimeout(function() {$('#my_div').hide("slide",{direction:"right"},500);},250);
return false;
});
```

My problem is this :  When I click on a link, it scrolls up at the top correctly but then automatically scrolls down ( seems to be around where I clicked ) and hide the content of my_div by sliding it and stay there.
I don't want it to scroll down to where I clicked but rather stay at the top. I tried everything I know but nothing works.

Note that if I put just hide() instead of hide("slide",{direction:"right"},500) there is no scroll down. Plus the scroll down occurs on Firefox and Opera but not in Chromium.

Thanks for your help,

Nolhian

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two options:

1) Don't use a-links with anchors if you don't use the anchor part the way it was ment to.

2) stop the default event from occuring by passing on event to the click function and using preventDefault.

example:
.click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();  });

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer ! I already tried preventDefault but it doesn't work. What do you mean about a-links with anchors ? My links are in a <div id="pagelinks"> and are like so : <a class="pagenumber" href="/page/2" >2</a>

Comment: I think I miss something in your code: Whats the purpose? When clicking a link, clearly a new page is loaded (if not-> then why use a-links?). Why scroll to top in this document, when another document is beeing loaded shortly?

Comment: When clicking a link it it triggers an Ajax event so only part of the page is loaded, that's why I need to scroll top, it won't do it automatically. I'm using links because I still need the href to point to the right page :)

Comment: I think you are using the a-links wrong in this case. You can instead use: <span target="some.url">a fake link</span>, then you wont have to deal with any scrollTop problems. The click method reads out the target property and fetches html from that url.